# Uniswap router v2 pairing

Tags: solidity, uniswapv2

I'm writing a token contract, and I'm wondering how pairing works precisely. I want to pair my token A with custom token B. I will add liquidity with x amount of token A and y amount of token B to create a liquidity pool. So the code would usually look like this when pairing with ETH

```
IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory()).createPair(address(this), _uniswapV2Router.WETH());
```

Now since I'm paring with token B, I have

```
 IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory()).createPair(address(this), address(TOKEN_B));
```

Now what I'm not sure about do you always create a pair with WETH and then the liquidity pool handles transfers from token A -> WETH -> token B. What's the downside of directly pairing with a custom token instead of WETH? Just a side not I want to identify the sale transaction in the transfer function by checking if the recipient is uniswapV2Pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pair your **token A** and **token B**, you'll bypass the intermediate step of converting to **WETH**, and you can only `swap` **token A** for **token B** and vice versa within that specific liquidity pool.

But if you pair **token A** with **WETH**, you can easily `swap` **token A** for many other tokens (As long as it is paired to WETH). Since **WETH** is popular, it can be traded with almost all tokens.

Direct Pairing:

```
Token A <-> Token B
```

Pairing with WETH:

```
Token A <-> WETH <-> Token B
Token A <-> WETH <-> Token C
```

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks for the explanation. In that case, how do I identify the sell event? Since with direct pairing, I can check if the recipient is that pair?

Comment: You can check the `swap` events, you can read the `Transfer` events from your liquidity Pool